# Unable to Boot Ubuntu after Windows 8.1 Installation.

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 from live USB and after confirming that it s working properly i installed windows 8.1 from CD.
Now i am unable to boot Ubuntu. Although Windows is working fine.

Comment: Windows doesn't play nice with Ubuntu, so it's generally a good idea to install Ubuntu after Windows. That being said, the second answer in the above link dealing with the `boot-repair` utility will likely help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows replaces the boot loader at the start of the drive with its own. All you have to do is reinstall the GRUB boot loader Ubuntu uses.

You can boot up on a Live DVD or USB stick and reinstall GRUB to your drive by opening a terminal and issuing the "sudo grub-install /dev/sda" command (assuming your boot drive appears as /dev/sda). Remember to install to the DRIVE (eg: sda), not the partition (eg: sda1).

In future, install Ubuntu after Windows to save headaches.